# How to make Admob InterstitialAd be landscape in Android

Tags: android, admob

Hey guys I am using GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.3.0.jar of Admob, in my landscape game, I wanna InterstitialAd to be force landscape. I have try to set

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" 
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
    </activity>
```

in the manifest file, but the InterstitialAd orientation still follow the orientation of my android phone. How to make it fixed landscape? Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

?? Why wouldn't you want the ad to show in the orientation in which the user has the device? If they are playing in landscape then the ad will show in landscape. If they have rotated the device then it will show in portrait but it will be oriented correctly for the user.

I think you are worrying for no reason.

Comment: What if the user is playing a landscape only game but has forced its phone to portrait mode ? The user will be playing landscape but will have rotated ads. I think it's a bad user experience.

Comment: When you start an app in portrait mode and then you rotate a phone a preloaded ad is still in portrait format, seems we have to manually reset a preloaded ad on orientation change and load a new one